# Mailchimp object not found django ('module' object has no attribute 'Mailchimp')

Tags: python, django

I wanted to use mailchimp in my Django app.

so I did the following:

`pip install mailchimp`

and in my **view.py** I'm doing this

```
def testtemplates(request):
    API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
    LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_LIST
    api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)

    l = api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': 'test@mail.com'})
    return HttpResponse(escape(repr(l)))
```

While I can see the class Mailchimp in
`venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailchimp.py`

I'm getting this error when I simply hit the URL
`'module' object has no attribute 'Mailchimp'`
This error is coming on line      `api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)`

I believe I'm using the package correctly there must be some small stupid error or something which is out of my sight.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for the response, yes the env is the same I also tried uninstalling and installing Mailchimp again.
the second thing I am returning HttpResponse in the end, I'll update my question regarding that

Comment: Do you have a `mailchimp.py` somewhere in your project that is clashing `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailchimp.py`?

Comment: I think clash would be the reason, i can only see one package of mailchip there mailchimp.py, and i just tried another library it worked fine for me https://pypi.org/project/mailchimp3/

Comment: @Alasdair I wonder what's wrong I'm doing with the first one

Comment: I mean is there a `mailchimp.py` in your Django project, not in your `venv`. If you add `print(mailchimp.__file__)`, to your view, then it should show you the location of the file  in the runserver output.

Comment: i'm getting this path
[  '/home/rehman/projects/comparedjs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailchimp/__init__.pyc' ]

Comment: yes this is the issue, i just checked mailchimp3 installed path and it has the class for Mailchimp but the older one is empty __init__.pyc file, how do i fix this

Comment: If your requirements file has the correct version, you could create a new virtual environment. Or you could try `pip uninstall mailchimp`. As a last resort you could try removing the `packages/mailchimp/__init__.pyc` file, but normally I'd try to avoid manually editing/removing files in the virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your import looks like, but mine is like this and you don't need to prefix in the code.

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

def testtemplates(request):
    API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
    LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_LIST
    api = Mailchimp(API_KEY)

    etc...
```

Of course this is simple, not Django